# URL Escape in Uppercase

Tags: url, encoding, abap

I have a requirement to escape a string with url information but also some special characters such as '<'.

Using cl_http_utility=>escape_url this translates to '%3c'. However due to our backend webserver, it is unable to recognize this as special character and takes the value literally.  What it does recognize as special character is '%3C' (C is upper case).  Also if one checks http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp it shows the value with all caps as the proper encoding.

I guess my question is is there an alternative to cl_http_utility=>escape_url that does essentially the same thing except outputs the value in upper case?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add a small demo program for the issue? I strongly suspect that the problem is somewhere else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the string function.

```
l_escaped = escape( val    = l_unescaped 
                    format = cl_abap_format=>e_url ).
```

Other possible formats are e_url_full, e_uri, e_uri_full, and a bunch of xml/json stuff too.  The string function *escape* is documented pretty well, demo programs and all.